# Make 2 divs display side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display google & facebook sign buttons side by side in a webpage.I'm using bootstrap social to display Facebook button and Google API to display Google button.By default I'm able to display them one below the other but when I try to display them one beside the error I'm not getting the desired output..

HTML Code..

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
       <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="sample_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com">
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script> 

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
       <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Happy+Monkey' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       <link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

       <title>Login Page</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <div class ="google">
        <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>         <!--Google signup button-->
       </div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <!--FB signu&nbsp;p button-->
        <div class="facebook" style="float: left;">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" onclick="facebookSignIn();" style="width:220px;">
        <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Connect with Facebook
        </a>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Current Output..

[image: sign in]

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could share a fiddle with us..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
       <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="sample_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com">
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script> 

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
       <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Happy+Monkey' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       <link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

       <title>Login Page</title>
       </head>
       <body><div class ="google">
        <div style="float:left;" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">goooogle</div>         
       </div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <!--FB signu&nbsp;p button-->
        <div class="facebook" style="float: left;">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" onclick="facebookSignIn();" style="width:220px;">
        <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Connect with Facebook
        </a>
        </div></body>
```

Comment: How do put space between them?? Putting "&nbsp;" in the above code is not working..

Answer (score 1):

Remove `&nbsp;`, to `.google` and `.facebook` you can give `display: inline-block;` or you can give to both `float: left;`

Answer (score 0):

Use This CSS Style code:

```
.google{
float:left;
}
.facebook{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css code:

```
.google, .facebook {
   float:left; 
}
```

Or

```
.google, . facebook{
    display:inline-block;
}
```